# rowversion in SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I'm working on an SQL Azure Database.

I would like to add a rowversion column to a table in my database but i can't find the type "rowversion"!

is it the "timestamp" type ? if so ! i have read that the timestamp is deprecated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same thing.  Rowversion is the "later" version - timestamp is deprecated because it doesn't match the standard SQL spec for timestamp.

If you don't have rowversion in your database, use timestamp.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Only the *name* `timestamp` has been deprecated, because it was a horrible choice for a name that represents the `rowversion` data type - since it has nothing to do with date or time (as it should, if based on what is specified in ANSI). The `timestamp` and `rowversion` types are 100% compatible and interchangeable.

And while the name has been deprecated, you may as well continue using it. Even in SQL Server 2012, `rowversion` isn't even in `sys.types` and if you create a table using `rowversion` it is stored in `sys.columns` as `timestamp` and gets scripted as the latter if you later generate a script of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.what_the(heck ROWVERSION);

SELECT t.name 
  FROM sys.types AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
  ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
  OR t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE 
  c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.what_the');
```

Result:

```
name
---------
timestamp
```

This is a little tongue in cheek, you absolutely should use `rowversion` and not `timestamp` for future compatibility reasons, I'm just poking a little fun because once again Microsoft has a "do as we say, not as we do" deprecation policy. In the case of SQL Azure you may have to choose `timestamp` for now until they sort this out - it seems kind of short-sighted to me that they would continue using the old name since it continues to cause so much confusion out there. `<shrug>`

P.S. Where are you seeing this? In the web-based SQL Azure table designer? I suspect you can use either `rowversion` or `timestamp` if you use a query editor to create your table, instead of limiting yourself to the list presented to you in the dropdown in the table designer UI.

Comment: Also note that "Federated members do not support the timestamp and rowversion data type." - [Federation Guidelines and Limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh597469)

Comment: @FernandoCorreia good point, I wasn't even thinking about federation.